# Ant Design Input Component not updating value

Tags: reactjs, antd

I try to get value from backend and append the result to the input field value, but it will not be updated.

Currently I use Ant Design Forms and if input field is moved out of Form it works.

```
import { version, Input, Form } from "antd";

function View() {
      const [LegalName, setLegalName] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
          .get("/afterlogin/OrgFullPictureGet/3", config)
          .then(response => {
            setLegalName(response.data.name);

          })
          .catch(error => {
            // console.log(error.response.data.errors);
          });
      }, []);

      const onFinish = values => {
        //onFinish logic here
        console.log(values);
      };
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Form name="nest-messages" onFinish={onFinish}>
            <Form.Item
              name={["user", "LegalName"]}
              label={<span>Legal Name</span>}

            >
              <Input
                placeholder={"Your business legal name"}
                value={LegalName}
                onChange={e => setLegalName(e.target.value)}
              />
            </Form.Item>
          </Form>


        </div>
      );
    }
```

the value does not get appended on the input field

Comment: @Pranshu Saxena show your Input component code.

Comment: @VahidAkhtar He is using [Ant Design](https://ant.design/components/input/).

Comment: did you log `response.data.name` inside `then`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When using `name` field on the `Form.Item`, it means that the Form component will handle the `value` and `handleChange` on the field from then on. You do not need need to add them. So if you need to add `value` and `handleChange`, remove `name` prop from `Form.Item` as you see [here](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-without-form-create)

But using in most cases, you would want to use them. In that case the alternative is to use the `form.setFieldValues` to set the required values:

```
const [form] = Form.useForm();
const [legalName, setLegalName] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
  axios
    .get("/afterlogin/OrgFullPictureGet/3", config)
    .then(response => {
      form.setFieldsValue({
        legalName: response.data.name
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // console.log(error.response.data.errors);
    });
}, []);

return (
  <Form name="nest-messages" form={form} onFinish={onFinish}>
    <Form.Item name="legalName" label={<span>Legal Name</span>}>
      <Input placeholder={"Your business legal name"} />
    </Form.Item>
  </Form>
);
```

[`useForm` & `setFieldValue` Demo docs](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-control-hooks)

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yczjcz?file=index.js)